# Weighting contributions from depth of field sampling

Tags: raytracing

I'm trying to add some depth of field to a simple ray caster. I'm using the method where, for each pixel, rays are cast through the focal point for this pixel from several random "eye" positions inside a small aperture area, and the color samples from each of these rays are averaged together.

My question is: how should these samples be weighted for the average? Is it just a straight unweighted average or is it weighted based on where the ray starts from? For instance, I could weight it so that rays from the center of the aperture have maximum weight, and have minimum weight at the extreme limit of the aperture.

I'm trying to understand it in terms of the optics: I understand the basic idea that a lens will only focus points at a specific distance away, and anything closer or further away will be kind of smeared out when it reaches the retina/frame. I assume this smearing means that the intensity of the light will be smeared out as well, i.e., reduced on a per pixel basis. But I can't figure out how to apply this to my implementation. I know how far away the point being rendered is: do I need to use this to weight it based on how close it is to the focal-distance, or does the natural sampling process take this into account? If I do need to weight it based on this, what does the weighting function look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it both ways, and it looks like a straight average will all samples weighted equal works best. If anyone can provide additional information to either challenge or reinforce (and hopefully explain) this, I'd appreciate it!